# Can a project created by c# template use WPF in vs2010?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I have a simple question about WPF library.

I have a C# template created by my company in Visual Studio 2010.

After I create a project using this template, can I still use WPF library for this project?
If so, what is the simple step to achieve this?

Comment: Any .NET project can reference any .NET library.  Whether that library is useful in that project is another matter.  How was the project template created in the first place?  Did it extend an existing WPF project template?  If you want a WPF application then you need certain scaffolding in place and the way to do that is to extend the original WPF Application project template.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The template I have does not extend any existing WPF project template. And I don't have any right to modify the template itself. I can only use the template to create projects. How to referenc the project to WPF liabrary after I create the project using this template? Thank you.

Comment: If the project template creates a winforms application, that will be of no use in WPF. Have your company update the template to use current technology. Otherwise you will have to manually add all revelant references and remove useless components (such as `System.Windows.Form.Application` and the like)

Comment: What type of application does this template create?  While you can mix and match WinForms and WPF, it is intended to be a stop-gap measure only while you migrate from a WinForms solution to a WPF solution.  What's in the application and what's in the library that you want make use of?

Comment: It would be a dialog box based application. After your description, I think it is not easy to replace the original dialog box with WPF UI.